# How can I use the flags logic to turn on/off the lights and rotations?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> objectsToRotate = new List<Transform>();
    public bool turnOnRotationLights = false;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public Light[] lights;
    public Material material;
    public Vector3 targetAngle = new Vector3(-90f, 0f, 0f);

    private bool rotationLightsOn = true;

    // 0,31,191
    // 255,0,0

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (turnOnRotationLights)
            StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(turnOnRotationLights == true && rotationLightsOn == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SetTrue());

            rotationLightsOn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rotationLightsOn = true;
        }

        if (rotationSpeed == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
            {
                Transform t = objectsToRotate[i].transform;
                float newAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(t.localEulerAngles.x, targetAngle.x, Time.deltaTime);
                t.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(newAngle, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if (turnOnRotationLights)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToRotate[i].Rotate(new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    public void setHighlight(bool highlight)
    {
        if (highlight)
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(0, 31, 191));
        }
        else
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(255,0,0));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SetTrue()
    {
        setHighlight(true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        StartCoroutine(SetFalse());
    }

    IEnumerator SetFalse()
    {
        setHighlight(false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }
}
```

It was working fine without the two flags turnOnRotationLights and rotationLightsOn this is how the code looks like before adding and using this two flags :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> objectsToRotate = new List<Transform>();
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public Light[] lights;
    public Material material;
    public Vector3 targetAngle = new Vector3(-90f, 0f, 0f);

    // 0,31,191
    // 255,0,0

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
            {
                Transform t = objectsToRotate[i].transform;
                float newAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(t.localEulerAngles.x, targetAngle.x, Time.deltaTime);
                t.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(newAngle, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
        {
            objectsToRotate[i].Rotate(new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    public void setHighlight(bool highlight)
    {
        if (highlight)
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(0, 31, 191));
        }
        else
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(255,0,0));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SetTrue()
    {
        setHighlight(true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        StartCoroutine(SetFalse());
    }

    IEnumerator SetFalse()
    {
        setHighlight(false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }
}
```

but there are two problems :

- When running the game the lights and rotation start at the beginning.
- I can't control the lights and rotation on/of while the game is running in runtime.

I want :

- When the game start also start the lights and rotation if the public flag is true.
- While the game is running in runtime to be able to turn off/on both lights and rotation.

The way I used it with the flags it's not working good. When I turn it off at runtime only some orations stop and the lights keep on and it's all messed.

Answer (score 1):

When you have something which is animated and which does different animations depending on its state, then that sounds like something you might want to consider doing with the [animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html) instead of coding yourself. It allows you to design complex animations using visual tools instead of writing code, and then allows you to switch between those animations with just a single C# method call.

1. Add an animator to the light-prefab
2. Create an animation controller for that animator
3. Create two states for it: off and on.
4. Create a bool-parameter.  Let's call it "on".
5. Create transitions between those two animations which are triggered by the state of that bool-parameter.
6. Make the on-animation looping.
7. Design the on-animation as described in the manual. That would be mostly the rotation looping from 0° to 360° over the course of 0.5 seconds and the light source being on on both points of that rotation curve while it's off on the off-animation.
8. Now all programming you need to do is `GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("on", true)` to switch the light on and `GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("on", false)` to switch it off again.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch the two Coroutine for one InvokeRepeating. You can supply how often it should be invoked and it will continue until you stop it. Now your lights won't toggle on Start anymore if your lightSwitch is off. If you want to start it at a later time, you can call StartLights and Stop it anytime with StopLights. Since your rotation is handled in Update, all we need to do is have a bool for that around your whole logic and switch to trigger if you want to stop or start it.

```
public bool lightSwitch;
public bool doRotation;

void Start(){
  if (lightSwitch)
    StartLights();
}

void Update(){
  if (doRotation){
    // whole rotation code
  }
}

void ToggleLight() {
  lightSwitch = !lightSwitch;
  LightLogic();
}

void ToggleRotation() {
  doRotation = !doRotation;
}

public void StopLights() {
   CancelInvoke();
}

public void StartLights() {
   InvokeRepeating("ToggleLight", 0f, 0.5f);
}

public void LightLogic() {
  material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
  material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
  if (lightSwitch) {       
    material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(0, 31, 191));
  } else {           
    material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(255,0,0));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> objectsToRotate = new List<Transform>();
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public Material material;
    public Vector3 targetAngle = new Vector3(-90f, 0f, 0f);
    public bool go = false;

    private bool lightsOn = true;

    // 0,31,191
    // 255,0,0

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (go)
            StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
            {
                Transform t = objectsToRotate[i].transform;
                float newAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(t.localEulerAngles.x, targetAngle.x, Time.deltaTime);
                t.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(newAngle, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if (go)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToRotate[i].Rotate(new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        if (go && lightsOn)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SetTrue());

            lightsOn = false;
        }

        if(go == false)
        {
            lightsOn = true;
        }
    }

    public void setHighlight(bool highlight)
    {
        if (highlight)
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(0, 31, 191));
        }
        else
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(255,0,0));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SetTrue()
    {
        setHighlight(true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        if (go)
            StartCoroutine(SetFalse());
    }

    IEnumerator SetFalse()
    {
        setHighlight(false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        if (go)
            StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to click the checkmark to mark this answer as Accepted.